# Wikipedia story about Bill Thurston's death

Tags: ho.history-overview

I did not know whom to ask about this rather unsettling piece of news. Apparently [Wikipedia has announced Bill Thurston's death on August 21, 2012](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/William_Thurston). I could not independently verify it. Is this true?

Comment: Here is an E-mail I got from Max Karoubi about this. It is certainly not a joke.

Comment: *From: *Dylan Thurston <dpt@math.columbia.edu <mailto:dpt@math.columbia.edu>>
*Subject: **Bill Thurston, 1946-2012*
*Date: *August 22, 2012 5:38:27 AM GMT+02:00
*
*
Dear all,

Bill passed away at 8PM on August 21 in Rochester, NY.  He was
surrounded by family, and went very peacefully, after a fight with
melanoma since spring 2011.

Please pass this on as appropriate.

Sincerely,
Dylan Thurston

Comment: Some googling for news about Thurston in the past 24 hours also reveals several obituaries, e.g. http://obituaries.pressherald.com/obituaries/mainetoday-pressherald/obituary.aspx?n=william-thurston-gleason-bill&pid=159323516

Comment: @ Max  The link points to a different Bill Thurston.

Comment: @Damian Rössler This is so sad. May he rest in peace.

Comment: There is also a meta.MO thread dedicated to this very sad news http://tea.mathoverflow.net/discussion/1429/loss-of-a-member/ 

Comment: I've closed this question since there is no good answer to this. (Closing as 'off topic' seemed like the least inappropriate option, but it does not accurately reflect the reason for closing.)

Comment: I don't think that the question should be closed as off-topic.  It has a valid (if tragic) answer, the one that Damien posted as a comment.

Comment: My comment should have read 'no other good answer', I appear to have skipped a word. I picked 'off topic' because the other options seemed offensive to me. If you prefer, I could simply lock the question so there is no posted reason, but that would also lock the comment thread which is not desirable.

Comment: I re-edited the question, given the sad answer, for what I hope are understood by the OP as good intentions. 

Comment: @ Benjamin Steinberg    I am fine with your re-editing. 

Comment: I just want to share this link to the New York Times with you. 

http://www.nytimes.com/2012/08/23/us/william-p-thurston-theoretical-mathematician-dies-at-65.html


Comment: This is heartbreaking. What a loss.